# Android Tab Layout with many tabs

Tags: android, tabs

I am creating an application which uses Tab Layout. The requirement of the app is that there should be many tabs. Making 4-5 tabs on the tab bar was ok. But when more tham 5 tabs are added, it gets very compressed. Is there a way in android where i can have many tabs and not make it look compressed? maybe some what like having a "More" button on the tab or having horizontal scrollable tabs?

I forgot to mention this earlier that it should work on android 2.2(api 8)

Thanks

Comment: why dont you introduce Horizontal Scrolling in your tabs?

Comment: got similar app, but I get rid off tab and just add arrows left/right with title between.

Comment: Horizontally scrollable tabs can be the recommended approach. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html and the section "Categories"

Comment: Checkout [ViewPageIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) to see how many swipeable tabs can be implemented using the ViewPager.

Comment: TheModernInk & Jave will it work on api 8?
goodm thanks that can be a good option
Waqas are  you telling the same thing which Jave 's link shows?

Answer (score 17):

For tab layout add the line

```
app:tabMode="scrollable"
```

to your XML file, for example

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorSecondary"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorSecondary"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="5dp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```